# .bashrc doesn't export the path?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, path

Every time I login to our company cluster, I first get a Kerberos ticket and then try to submit a job, but it fails to find spark-ubmit:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./pipeline.runtime/scripts/vpspark-submit.sh crow-env/ /user/gsamaras/crow_spm-1.0.2.3.tar.gz --properties-file $SPARK_CONF_PROPERTIES --num-executors 1 foo.py 
./pipeline.runtime/scripts/vpspark-submit.sh: line 51: spark-submit: command not found
```

If however, I source the .bashrc, it works fine.

```
>> cat .bashrc
[ -f /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
export PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=~/tripodrt-spark/conf/
export SPARK_CONF_PROPERTIES=~/tripodrt-spark/conf/spark-overrides-tt.conf
```

Why? I would expect that .bashrc runs on login. I am on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `bash` manual:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, `bash`
>          reads  and  executes  commands  from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.

So if your shell is a login shell, `~/.bashrc` is not read.

I would put additions to `PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` instead, and/or possibly source `~/.bashrc` from there.

Some shells makes a distinction between two or three types of shell initialization files:

1. A *profile* file that is read by login shells.
2. A file that is read by interactive shells.
3. And possibly, a file that is read by non-interactive shells, i.e. scripts.

For `bash`:

1. `~/.bash_profile`
2. `~/.bashrc`
3. Whatever file `$BASH_ENV` points to.

The point of separating the *profile* startup script from the script read by interactive shells is to let you do (potentially heavy) set-up tasks for all your future shell sessions once and for all. This usually involves setting the `PATH` at the minimum, but also any other exported variables (i.e. environment variables).

The interactive shell initialization script (`~/.bashrc` in the case of `bash`) then only needs to do thing specifically needed for interactive shells. This includes setting shell variables like `PS1` that shouldn't be exported, and defining aliases and functions etc. You should also set up environment variables that need to be set for this session and any started process from this session, such as `GPG_TTY` (`GPG_TTY="$(tty)"`) if you're using GnuPG.

I tend to `source $HOME/.bashrc` from my `~/.bash_profile` after setting my `PATH` and adjusting my `umask` the way I want them, and let `~/.bashrc` set up history file variables, the `PS1` prompt, `PAGER` and `EDITOR` and a few aliases and functions and whatnot. (That's half a lie; I *actually* `exec` the `ksh93` shell from my profile if I can find it, but if I can't, I continue with `bash`). I also *renice* my shell in the interactive shell initialization file (with `renice -n 4 $$`), because I often work on a shared machine with loads of other people that needs the CPU more than I do (but that's just me).

The `ksh93` shell uses

1. `~/.profile`
2. `~.kshrc` (or whatever `$ENV` points to)

`ksh93` is a bit saner than `bash` in that it knows there is such a thing as an interactive login shell, so it reads `$ENV` (if it is set) for those shell sessions too, after reading `~/.profile`.

The `pdksh` shell also reads `~/.kshrc` for non-interactive shells, which annoys me (and breaks a few important scripts that I use), so I have

```
case $- in
    *i*)    ;;
    *)      return      ;;
esac
```

at the top of my `~/.kshrc` file.

Comment: So you mean to copy the export commands I have in the `.bash_profile`? There is no such a file in my directory... :/

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, create `.bash_profile` in your home directory and add the `export` commands there, *or*, add a single line saying `source $HOME/.bashrc`.

Comment: Also, it's typical for "set once" variables to be in `.bash_profile` (eg `$PATH`,  `$SPARK_CONF_DIR`) and only things that need to be set for every subshell (eg _aliases_ and _functions_) to be set in `.bashrc`.